# How do I bind two disk frames together?

Tags: r, data.table, disk.frame

I have two disk frame and each are about 20GB worth of files.

It's too big to merge as data tables because the process requires more than the memory I have available. I tried using this code: `output <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2))`

The wrinkle is that I'd like to also run `unique` since there might be dups in my data.

Can I use the same code with `rbindlist` on two disk frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. You just do `rbindlist.disk.frame(list(df1, df2))`

I need to implement `bind_rows` at some point too!

Comment: Thanks! I'm running rbindlist.disk.frame on two 30M rows x 8 columns disk frames. It's been running for about two hours and the progress indicator hasn't moved. Is that normal?

Comment: Eh... Not normally. 30m rows? And mmhave big columns. This should be sub minute. But of course depends on your column size

Comment: Weird. The machine is still responsive, like I can press stop and it stops immediately. I wonder if the machine is just busy right now. I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: It's working! Strangely, the progress bar isn't showing up

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug. Let me look into it. I am currently reworking the whole NSE system so bugs are likely. Also it's pre-v1 so thanks for testing. :)